# Intento reemplazar unos bytes de un fichero binario, pero no lo hace correctamente, en Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, archivo

¿Alguien con experiencia en manipulación de ficheros?

- 1º Bloque de código, crea un fichero de texto.
- 2º Bloque de código, reemplaza las primeras letras del fichero dejando intacto el resto. (TODO CORRECTO)

  El input está solo para hacer una pausa.
- 3º Bloque de código, intenta "reemplazar" igualmente los primeros tres bytes del fichero pero, no lo hace bién. Me graba esos tres bytes pero borrándome el resto del fichero empequeñeciéndolo a esos tres bytes.

¿Hay alguna forma más correcta de reemplazar bytes binarios de un fichero dejando intacto el resto?

```
#Escribir y crear si no existe con .write()
archivo_texto = open("archivo.txt", "w") # Nombre de archivo y modo de acceso

frase = "Estupendo día para estudiar Pyhon\n el miércoles"

archivo_texto.write(frase) # Lo graba

archivo_texto.close()

#Con esto escribimos reemplazando el texto en la posición determinada por ".seek()"
archivo_texto=open("archivo.txt", "r+")

archivo_texto.seek(0) # Esto lo que hace es posicionar el puntero donde queramos, al ser (0) nos imprime el texto desde el principio

frase="Reemplazamos"
archivo_texto.write(frase)
archivo_texto.close()


a = input("PULSA ENTER PARA CONTINUAR")


archivo_texto=open("archivo.txt", "wb") # En modo binario

archivo_texto.seek(0) # Esto lo que hace es posicionar el puntero donde queramos, al ser (0) nos imprime el texto desde el principio

frase=(b"\x01\x02\x03")

archivo_texto.write(frase)

archivo_texto.close()
```

Comment: http://bit.ly/SOesPASTE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
archivo_texto=open("archivo.txt", "r+b") # En modo binario
```

Espero te sirva bro

Comment: Lee [https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) y mejora tu respuesta.